# Javascript hidden items on scroll down

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hogan.js

I am a novice here on node and Javascripting. I need to implement an infinite scroll without loading more data on scroll down. What I want to do is to load all data once and then apply classes on them such that when i scroll down it unhides a number of the items...

Is there a plugin for it(all I could find involve making ajax calls)

Kindly let me know if there is already such a module available.

If not then what would be the best way of achieving it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify infinite scrolling? If you want to load all your data up front, display it on a list and have that list be infinitely scrollable, you must have infinite data, which you cannot load up front. Do you want the scroll to wrap and start from the beginning when you get to the end?

Comment: I have data that is coming from mongo and data is such that after i sort it once and make ajax call through jscroll again it might return me some repeated data, to avoid that I want to load everything upfront, but don't display it to the end user, hence give an impression of infinite scrolling... I hope it makes some sence now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get what I want using this logic, I hope it will help other, if they are in similar situation, the jquery code is listed here

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() && $(".main > .hidden").length > 0) {
         i = 0;
         while (i < 2) {
             $('.main > .hidden').first().fadeIn(800).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
             i++;
         };
         alert($('.main > .hidden').last())
     }
 });
```

For mark up code try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akC8q/).